# Replace data on specific column and row

Tags: bash, shell

I currently new to shell scripting and i am having an issue in replacing data. I need to replace the data of a specific column and row.

Below is a random database:

```
test:test1:test2:test3:test4    
example:example1:example2:example3:example4    
sample:sample1:sample2:sample3:sample4
```

for example, I would like to replace the word "test3" into "changed".. how do i achieve this? i tried several command like

```
awk -F : 'NR==n{$4=a}1' n="$row" a="$replace" test.txt
sed -i "$row"'s/\S\+/'"$replace"'/4' test.txt
```

although there is no error when i run those command, it did not replace my data either.
anyone can give me some help on this problem..?

Comment: What's the value of `row` and `replace` variables?

Comment: What's wrong with `sed 's/test3/changed/g' file` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an `sed` one-liner (using in-place editing):

```
#!/bin/bash

cat > /tmp/file <<EOF
test:test1:test2:test3:test4    
example:example1:example2:example3:example4    
sample:sample1:sample2:sample3:sample4
EOF

row=1
column=4
replace=changed
sed -i "$row"'s/^\(\([^:]*:\)\{'"$(($column - 1))"'\}\)[^:]*/\1'"$replace"'/' /tmp/file

cat /tmp/file
```

Answer (score 1):

Your awk version works fine for me with a minor modification:

```
$ row=1
$ replace=changed
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}NR==n{$4=a}1' n="$row" a="$replace" file
test:test1:test2:changed:test4    
example:example1:example2:example3:example4    
sample:sample1:sample2:sample3:sample4
```

I have defined the Output Field Separator `OFS` so that lines which are modified still have `:` between each field. To overwrite the original file, you can just do `awk '...' file > tmp && mv tmp file`.